# Export Excel sheet to PDF using Macros and values of another table

Tags: vba, excel, macros, excel-2013

I'm new in Excel Macros and have no experience with VB or any language.

I have a sheet with a Price List, in this we have a field with a dropdown list with Contact Info (mail and cellphone) of our Salesman.

A second sheet contain a table with Name and ContactInfo.

Today, i use the dropdown to choose the salesman and export to pdf to specific directory.

I'm looking to export to PDF using a Macro doing these things. I've tried some macros without success. I want to use the name @Name to save in directory and @ContactInfo to replace in a specific field of pricelist.

What i have:

```
Sub MAKEPDF()
Dim dvCell As Range
Dim inputRange As Range
Dim c As Range
Dim i As Long


 'Which cell has data validation
Set dvCell = Sheets("NUEVA LISTA").Range("A3")
 'Determine where validation comes from
Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

arrVendedores = Array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", "Name7")

i = 1
 'Begin our loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each c In inputRange
    dvCell = c.Value

        ChDir "D:\Google Drive\Lista de Precios\temp\" & arrVendedores(i)

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="(" & Format(Range("A4"), "yyyy-mm-dd") & ") Lista de precios.pdf"

        'Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    i = i + 1
Next c
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

This save in PDF perfectly but that array don't work as expected causing error 9 (index) and is better use current data from Table1@Name.

Can anyone help me to goal this?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Shouldn't your array use i=0 to iterate? As in the arrVenderoes will be (0 to 6) by default not (1 to 7). You can check this in the Local windows in the editor.

Comment: It might be an idea to replace the i=1 and the i iteration with something like For i = LBound(arrVendedores) To UBound(arrVendedores), that way if you change the array you are safe. Then you can set the array earlier using the table you mentioned.

Comment: I've tried to use i+1 inside arrVendedores but fail, and.... i should use another variable like ii = i then use ii+1 inside arrVendedores

Comment: I take notice now about that.

Answer (score 0):

I found it hard to edit your code without seeing some of the inputs, but I got this to flow though with some dummy data.

```
    Sub MAKEPDF()
    Dim dvCell As Range
    Dim inputRange As Range
    Dim c As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     'Which cell has data validation
    Set dvCell = Sheets("NUEVA LISTA").Range("A3")
'You assigned the value of this cell later on but didn't use it so I removed the value assignment below.
     'Determine where validation comes from
    Set inputRange = Evaluate(dvCell.Validation.Formula1)

    arrVendedores = Array("Name1", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5", "Name6", "Name7")
    'you might want to assign this in code, not sure if it is the sheet names but I assumed it is if not and just filenames to use.

    For i = LBound(arrVendedores) To UBound(arrVendedores)
    'this allows an array of any size to be iterated over with having to change the code.
            ChDir "D:\Google Drive\Lista de Precios\temp\" & arrVendedores(i)

            Worksheets(arrVendedores(i)).ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="(" & Format(Range("A4"), "yyyy-mm-dd") & ") Lista de precios.pdf"
    'you had activeworksheet here but it didn't seem to be changing, so if I assume the array is sheet names this will export those sheet else you will need to change to suit.
            'Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Captain i use your comments to rebuild my macro

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Captain, based on your answer i made a new macro as following

```
Sub MakePDF4()

Dim myTable As ListObject
Dim myArray As Variant
Dim x As Long
Dim vendedorDatos As Range
Dim vendedorCampoDatos As Range



  Set myTable = Sheets("VENDEDORES").ListObjects("Table1")


  myArray = myTable.DataBodyRange


  For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)

        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Set vendedorCampoDatos = (Sheets("NUEVA LISTA").Range("A3"))
        vendedorCampoDatos = myArray(x, 2)

        'ChDir "D:\Google Drive\Lista de Precios\temp\" & myArray(x, 1)

        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="D:\Google Drive\Lista de Precios\temp\" & myArray(x, 1) & "\(" & Format(Range("A4"), "yyyy-mm-dd") & ") Lista de precios.pdf"

                'Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True

  Next x

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

It work as expected. I have some issue with setting ChDir with the array at the end but works when is setting in filename.

All data is in a unique file (may be i mispelled or confuse some words at explaining). One worksheet is the price list and a second worksheet contains the table with [@Name] and [@ContactInfo] of salesmen.

I use [@Name] to determinate in which directory i will save the PDF file and [@ContactInfo] to change in the worksheet of price list a unique field between salesmen